# Laragon Call to undefined function pg_pconnect() even i have enable the pgsql

Tags: laragon

I have set in `php.ini` but i cant use postgresql for my apache laragon version, the image just looks like below.

[image]

[image]

i even restarted the apache server but still didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. I need to restart my laptop to made that postgresql connection work. I don't know why restarting and reloading the apache web service not working.